# Sort values by address in MIPS

Tags: sorting, assembly, mips

I have the following addresses: 24,28,32,36 and 38 with the corresponding values of 2,4,3,5 and 1. How can I sort the values by the addresses in MIPS? So that the values would be in ascending order:1,2,3,4,5 and the addresses unchanged.

```
.data
a1:.word 2
a2:.word 1
a3:.word 3
a4:.word 5

.text
.globl main
main:
add $v0,$zero,$zero #counter
la $t0,a1 #get address of a1
lw $t1, 0($t0) #get value of a1
addi $t0,$t0,4
lw $t2, 0($t0) #get value of a2
slt $t3,$t2,$t1 #if t2<t1 ->t3=1
bne $t3,$zero,EXCHANGE

EXCHANGE:
move $t3,$t1
move $t1,$t2 #value of a2=1
move $t2,$t3 #value of a1=2
jr $ra
```

Comment: Start by writing your algorithm in C. Insertion or bubble sort should be the easiest to implement. After wonder how you could translate your array accesses, comparisons, array writes, loops, etc in MIPS asm. Then submit to SO any specific problem that you may encounter with your code and we will try to help you.

Comment: @AlainMerigot, I have edited the post. I have tried the following, which sorts the first 2 values, but I don't know how to sort them all...

Comment: Use [bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort). You scan your array, compare adjacent data and if they are unsorted you exchange them.  You just have to do this scan 5 times. Note you can fetch next value in array by `lw $t2, 4($t0)`. This will simplify comparisons of adjacent values. In your code, `bne EXCHANGE` will always lead to the same instruction. You should test value of $v0 to go back to main (and increment it at every step). There several other smaller problems, but fix your algorithm first.

Comment: @AlainMerigot, can you help me please? I'm kind of stuck...